# Is there a way to restrict/prevent copying of test scripts in ALM11

Tags: manual-testing, hp-alm

We are having issues with further phases of projects copying/re-using test scripts that are not suitable for that phase. When the desired outcome for that phase is not reached, our phase is being blamed.

Can anyone advise if there is a way of restricting/locking down/preventing test scripts from being copied by users?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the specific system, but it sounds to me like a culture or administrative problem.

- Are the different phases part of the same department?
- Who coordinates the test strategy?
- Is there an overall test budget?

Answer (score 0):

ALM provides an option to restrict access wherein you can give members only view access this disables copy & cut functions.